# Program moves scroll automatically to top in runtime built controls

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, scroll, runtime

I'm working on a project that needs to have a page with controls being repeated for the number of elements to be introduced. For example, if I need to configure 5 elements, i will have 5 rows with different controls to configure each one of them.

The controls are generated properly, they work independently, and all seems be working fine, but when I have multiple elements and the scroll bar appears, when I try to see the elements at the bottom the scroll automatically moves to top all the time.

I don't know if it can be avoied, or I could create this kind of control panels for the elements a different way, in some kind of control that right now I don't know if it exists or I just don't know how to use it for this function. I have all the functions to create the elements, so if I just have to recycle them to avoid that weird scroll behaviour is completely ok.

**Solved**

The problem was I was trying to put the scroll in a TabPage, and I needed to add a panel so the scroll is in the panel right now.

Comment: What type of control are you using as the container?  I'm assuming this is a WinForm project using one of the types of layout panels?

Comment: Well, all the elements are contained in a TabPage, and each element controls are contained in a panel, so, each element, has a panel, inside a Tab Page, and the panel has de different elements for the configuration. Don't know if this solved your doubt.

Comment: Which control is the one which is showing the scroll bar?

Comment: The Tab Page directly, I set the AutoScroll in the Tab Page.

Comment: Neither the `TabPage`, nor the `TabControl` class has an `AutoScroll` property.  Are you sure it's not a `Panel` control which is actually showing the scroll bar?

Comment: It's the TabPage, I'm pretty sure, and in the properties I have set the AutoScroll to True. I'm using Framework 4 if it's useful. Anyways, if you think that the problem is that I'm puting the scroll in the TabPage, should I add a Panel to avoid that problem?

Comment: Oops.  You're right.  Somehow I missed that.

Comment: Okay, that gave me the clue ^^ In the properties editor it appears the AutoScroll, but as you said, possibly it's not working properly anyways. I added a panel in the Tab Page, and now the scroll works properly. Thanks for the clue, if you want post the answer to give you the acceptation, since it's working now.

Comment: @Nuxy, Just a note to say you may have recieved more views on this question if you had tagged it with `winforms` as there a lot more people following that than  `scroll` `runtime` and `control`. You also don't mention that it is winforms in the quesiton, so I assume it is form Steven's comment :).

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the tags in case someone looks at it.